# Java obtain focus

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener

So I'm working on a **Piano like-program** in Java. I use a method that looks like this to trigger the correct sound for each key

```
public void Sound(String file){

    try{
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource(file));
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource(file)));
        clip.start();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    game.setFocusable(true);//my desperate try to regain focus on click...
    game.requestFocus();

}
```

What happends however is that after a period of time the `KeyListener` totaly **loses the focus** and the `KeyEvent` will not be triggerd anymore. If anyone knows how I can obtain focus on the `KeyListener` in the frame I would more then likely hear out on what you have to say.

What I have tried:

1. upon trigger set the panel to focus-able again
2. Made sure so that the program still runs in the background and indeed it is the panel losing focus.
3. Small other adjustments

Answer (score 5):

This has been asked many times previously, and in this situation the best solution is to **not use a KeyListener**. Instead use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) (click link), which behaves much better with regards to component focus.

Side recommendation: be sure to play your music **off** of the Swing event thread so as not to tie up this thread and freeze your GUI, and that all Swing calls be made **on** the Swing event thread.

Comment: So basicly create a seperate Thread for the Sounds to be ran in?

Answer (score 0):

You can force the focus adding the event with high priority queue.
I used this in application that scan barcodes and they have a very high speed in sending key events, and i need to use this in order to lose focus and gaing the focus in other fields.

You can do something like this, replace:

```
game.setFocusable(true);//my desperate try to regain focus on click...
    game.requestFocus();
```

with

```
      SunToolkit.flushPendingEvents();
      FocusEvent fl = new CausedFocusEvent(game, FocusEvent.FOCUS_GAINED, false, null,
                        CausedFocusEvent.Cause.TRAVERSAL);
       SunToolkit.postPriorityEvent(fl);
```

In this way i can guarantee that you will receive focus on game component right away

Best Regards !